# QwebView Not Playing Youtube Videos

Tags: python, video, youtube, pyqt4, qwebview

I recently started creating a web browser with PyQt4 until I ran into a problem. When I opened up youtube I realized that I could not view videos. After some research I found this solution:

```
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
```

However, when I did try opening up a youtube video it would show a blank screen.When I reloaded the page a short error message saying:

```
Play Back Is Not Supported On This Device
```

I tried watching a youtube video in a chromium browser and it worked perfectly fine.

I decided to also try this method:

```
self.Tab2Web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
```

The problem persisted.

The relevant pieces of code are the following:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QTabWidget):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(1283, 756)    
    QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
```

If I left something out, the complete code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Angrywasabi/ce3de1b1a24e9e61ed541a6695df067c)

Answer (score 0):

## Switching from PyQt4 to PySide

I had this problem too, and I think I may have an answer. `PyQt4` is not the only option for Qt Application development in python, there is `PySide` as well.

---

You can install it through pip:

`pip install -U PySide`

---

or a package manager (if you use linux):

`sudo apt-get install python-pyside`

or for python3:

`sudo apt-get install python3-pyside`

---

After the installation is completed, replace the PyQt4 imports with this instead:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide import QtWebKit
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
from PySide.QtCore import Slot as pyqtSlot
from PySide.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager
```

Everything should look and function exactly the same and hopefully the web browser's youtube should work correctly.

Another bonus is that PySide has the `LGPL` license while PyQt4 has the `GPL` license so, when using PySide, you do not have to release the source code for your web browser.